# How to write to a text file from Pl/SQL, PLS error 00363

Tags: oracle, plsql, utl-file

I am trying to write to a file from a procedure:

```
out_File := Utl_File.FOpen('C:\test', 'batotest.txt' , 'W');

  Utl_File.Put_Line(out_file , 'Hi this is text file!');
  Utl_File.FClose(out_file);
```

Compilation errors for PACKAGE xxxxxxxx

```
Error: PLS-00363: âûðàæåíèå 'OUT_FILE' íå ì.á. èñïîëüçîâàíî êàê àäðåñàò íàçíà÷åíèÿ
Line: 795
Text: out_File := Utl_File.FOpen('C:\test', 'batotest.txt' , 'W');

Error: PL/SQL: Statement ignored
Line: 795
Text: out_File := Utl_File.FOpen('C:\test', 'batotest.txt' , 'W');

Error: PLS-00363: 'OUT_FILE' íå ì.á. èñïîëüçîâàíî êàê àäðåñàò íàçíà÷åíèÿ
Line: 797
Text: Utl_File.FClose(out_file);

Error: PL/SQL: Statement ignored
Line: 797
Text: Utl_File.FClose(out_file);
```

So this is my code and it gives me this error, what is wrong?

Comment: found bug 
    create proc aProc (
    var in type
    outfile in type
)

Comment: i made it in only, read only

Comment: This is not your entire procedure and some of the error messages aren't in any language. Can you translate it please?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

First, you need to create a directory object to access the C:\test directory:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY CTEST AS 'C:\test';
GRANT READ ON DIRECTORY CTEST TO PUBLIC;
```

Next, you need to use this directory object when opening your file:

```
DECLARE
  out_File  UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
BEGIN
  out_File := UTL_FILE.FOPEN('CTEST', 'batotest.txt' , 'W');

  UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(out_file , 'Hi this is text file!');
  UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(out_file);
END;
```

Share and enjoy.

Comment: Could you please explain where does this file create? (on Oracle Server or the client )

Comment: @IsharaKularatna the file is created on the oracle server