# code to send the files into zip file through plsql or unix shell script

Tags: unix, plsql

i have written a pl/sql program to download attachments of all RFQ's. Now i have a requirement that i have to group that attachment into zip file.
can i achieve this by pl/sql or do i need to do this through shell script.

can u please help me with the possibility .

if there are total 100 attachments downloaded in to server path(individual attachments) and there are 10 files for each RFQ header.then i have to create 10 zip files with 10 files each of particular RFQ HEADER .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write to a text file from Pl/SQL, PLS error 00363](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23950850/how-to-write-to-a-text-file-from-pl-sql-pls-error-00363)

Comment: PL/SQL is not an elegant way to interact with the file system, it can do it but it is clunky.  My suggestion would be to write a java stored procedure to do the zipping and just invoke this from PL/SQL if needed.